# Bivariate probability help

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am studying for actuary exam 1/p and I have questions about bivariate probability notation. When I'm solving I am solving double integrals with a nested f(x,y)= xy + y^2  I notice that the problems ask for Pr (X<.5) or Pr(Y < .35). In math theory, how does this output coincide to the inputs? As far as I can tell, the difference is the way the integration is supposed to be ordered, starting with either dy or dx, and placing an x or y as a limit on the first integral.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[(X,Y) \in \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\right] = \iint_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dA
$$
so for example,
$$
\mathbb{P}[X<x]
 = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) dydx
 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy
$$
and similarly you can compute $\mathbb{P}[Y < y]$ by integrating the $x$ out over $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: So, when proving independent or dependent RVs of a joint probability function this is my pot of gold. Doesn't look too bad. Occasionally, I will run across a matrix of partial derivatives followed by an absolute value of a determinate - this seems to be an expansion of the relatively simple independent joint probability of RVs A & B = Pr(A) • Pr(B). Any clues where to start?

Comment: I should clarify, I have no idea which method this is

Comment: The one with the determinant and the matrix with partial derivatives which solves for a probability of the independent, joint RVs A and B, and the solution Pr(A&B) = Pr(A)•Pr(B).

Comment: @Gwopmeat joint pdf factors into regular pdfs iff variables are independent